# Closures keep ownership of local variables for longer than expected

Tags: iterator, rust, closures, borrow-checker

```
let array = [40];
let mut var = 60;

for element in array.iter().filter(|&x| {*x < var}) {
    var += 1; // Error
}

var += 1; // Fine again
```

To me this code seems completely legit, as the closure should be over by the time I actually access `var` outside of it.

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `var` because it is borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
5 |     for element in array.iter().filter(|&x| {*x < var}) {
  |                                        ---- borrow of `var` occurs here
6 |         var += 1; // Error
  |         ^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `var` occurs here
```

Why is `var` still borrowed when calling `var += 1` even though the scope of the closure should be already over? The result is needed to get to `var += 1`. While it is possible to do something like this without `filter`, it causes my code to be a lot less clear, so I would like to keep using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the closure should be over by the time I actually access

No. [Iterators are *lazy*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html). That means that the order of operations here is:

1. We call `next` on the combined iterator.
2. This calls `next` on the iterator from the array. Repeat this step until the condition is passed.
3. Run the body of the loop with the value.
4. Repeat the whole process.

You are capturing `val` inside the filter's closure. You also try to modify it in the loop. This would mean that there has to be a mutable reference and an immutable one at the same time, which is disallowed.

You could use `Cell` to have interior mutability:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    let array = [40];
    let var = Cell::new(60);

    for element in array.iter().filter(|&&x| x < var.get()) {
        var.set(var.get() + 1);
    }

    let mut var = var.get();
    var += 1;
}
```

Comment: So if I undersand everything correctly, using filter() creates a new struct containing the closure( and borrowing val) which exists until it goes out of scope, which happens once the iterator gets called and returns None after case the for loop is over and the filter struct is out of scope, meanimg that it stops borrowing val and I can mutate it again. In case this is true, I now finally understand how iterators work. Thanks, and sry for my bad english, I'm writing this on my phone.

Comment: @SleepingPanda yes. It creates a [`Filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Filter.html) struct that contains the closure and the closure attempts to immutably borrow `var`. The body of the loop attempts to mutate `var`. Ownership of that struct is transferred to the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Shepmaster's answer is correct (I didn't know iterators were *that* lazy), but if you don't want the `var` check (i.e. the `filter` condition) to change during the loop, you can use a [`move` closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/closures.html#move-closures):

```
filter(move |&x| *x < var)
```

Since `i32` implements `Copy`, the value of `var` will just be copied for the purposes of the closure.

Comment: This changes the (presumably desired) logic. I assume the filter should "dynamically" update with each iteration.

Comment: @Shepmaster I was under the impression that the expectation was that by the time the body of the loop is executed the filter has already done its job (hence the question why the borrow is still in force inside it).

Comment: Im my actually code `var` does not change, but it is a rather big struct, so using copy would be a bad move. Once I have some time I will test the performance with copy, as I only need a part of my struct for `filter()`. Thanks :)